# Groovy SQL: Print actual query sent to the DB

Tags: groovy

When using the Groovy SQL class, is there a way to see the raw SQL which is being sent to the DB. For example for the below code...

```
def starship_name =  mySql.firstRow("select name from starship where id = ${starShipId}".toString())?.name
```

I want to be able to see on the console something like.......

```
select name from starship where id = 8
```

Comment: wouldn't that `.toString()` there basically disable groovys automagic parmeterization and allow sql injections?

Comment: Also it means that's exactly the SQL that's being run, so logging to the console would just be a matter of printing it out

Comment: Actually I was getting the error 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1', turns out the problem was with my JDBC driver. But it told me to look at the syntax of my query which is what threw me off and made me want to print it out. So when is this problematic part being added to the query? It must be getting added by Groovy before it reaches the DB right?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string, print it and then execute it:

```
    def query = "select name from starship where id = ${starShipId}"
    println query
    def starship_name = mySql.firstRow(query)
```